# Able to enable row-click in Element UI for certain condition VueJS

Tags: vue.js, element-ui

I just want to ask how to enable the row click event in Element UI only for a certain condition. For example, the row should only be clicked if the status is 'Approved'

```
<el-table @row-click="view"> <!--the row can only be clicked if the status is 'Approved' -->
</el-table>
```

I don't have any idea about it. Or this code can be effective: `:row-clicked`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do something like, `@row-click="condition ? view : undefined"`. if `condition` is true it will call the function else nothing will happen.

You can also use `v-on="condition ? { 'row-click': view } : {}"`.

Comment: for example if the condition is came from data, something like this ```<el-table :data="dataList"  @row-click="dataList.status === 'Approved' ? view : undefined">``` that condition would work?